# Copying resource file to external storage on android not working

Tags: android

I'm working on a mediaplayer application and am trying to have some default songs get put on the phone in case the user doesn't have any on their phone (I'm pulling the list of actual songs via mediastore).

So I have the songs put in the res/raw folder and fun the following code to copy them. It seems to be copying ok (since astro file browser and other apps see them fine) but the mediastore still can't find them.

I think it's something with the permissions on the file but I'm not sure what. Anybody know why?

```
InputStream song = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.aquarel);

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), "aquarel.mp3");
Log.e(TAG, "File1: " + file.getPath());
OutputStream copySong = new FileOutputStream(file);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int readvalue = 0;
readvalue = song.read(buffer);

while (readvalue > 0) {
    copySong.write(buffer, 0, readvalue);
    readvalue = song.read(buffer);
}

copySong.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "When you add files to Android’s filesystem these files are not picked
>   up by the MedaScanner automatically.
>
> ...
>
> If you want your files to be added to the media library, you can do so
>   either by using the MediaStore content provider, or by using the
>   MediaScanner."

You can add them by sending a broadcast:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

([Source](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-files-to-androids-media-library-using-the-mediascanner/))